# Read double from serial port

Tags: java, serial-port, double

Im trying to read a double from a serial port.
I can read it in String, but when I parse the String to Double, the result makes no sense, and it's not the same from the String.

This is my code:

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event){
        switch(event.getEventType()) {

            case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[8];
                try {
                    while (inputStream.available()>0) {
                     int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                     String peso = new String (readBuffer, 0, numBytes, "UTF-8");
                     System.out.print(new String (readBuffer, 0, numBytes, "UTF-8"));
                    //double d = ByteBuffer.wrap(readBuffer).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN ).getDouble();
                    //System.out.print(d);
                     m_dWeightBuffer = Double.parseDouble(peso);
                     System.out.print(m_dWeightBuffer);
                     }
                     //System.out.print(new String (readBuffer, 0, numBytes, "UTF-8"));
                    } catch (IOException ex) {}
                break;

        } 
    }
```

But now, you know how I can convert this string to Double?

`System.out.print(new String (readBuffer, 0, numBytes, "UTF-8"));`
 
Output: `000.250` Good

`m_dWeightBuffer = Double.parseDouble(peso); 
System.out.print(m_dWeightBuffer);`
 Output: `0.00.0250.0` Bad

`System.out.println(new String (readBuffer, 0, numBytes, "UTF-8"));`
Output:

`0`

`0`

`0`

`.250`

Comment: I would be *extremely* surprised if `System.out.print(m_dWeightBuffer);` printed `0.00.0220.0`. I suspect your diagnostics are somewhat broken.

Comment: how can you be sure if all data has arrived? inputStream.read(readBuffer) might only provide a semi-complete message while the transmission is ongoing.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think is cause there is < CR >, cause printing with `print` it prints good, but if i println with `println` the output is like `0` `0` `0` ``.250`. (I will add this output at question)
@datahaki I know cause i tried with hyperterminal and teraterm, the only output is the weight. (I'm using a scale)

Comment: @DavidM: Well printing a `double` value isn't going to include a carriage return. I suggest you log the length of data you've read, and then *just* the double. It's also not clear what the protocol is here, but is there any way to note the end of a message? How do you know the breaks between messages?

Comment: you should rework and reformat your question, writing your last working code, ONE error output, and ONE expected output :) As for now we are unable to read or understand all your attempts.

Comment: BTW, is m_dWeightBuffer used in a thread-safe context, being a non-local variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
 public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event){
            switch(event.getEventType()) {

                case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
                    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[8];


                    try {
                         while (inputStream.available()>0) {
                             int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                             peso += new String (readBuffer, 0, numBytes, "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\s+","").replaceAll("\\n", "").replaceAll("\\r", "");

                         }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {}

                    break;

            } 
    }
```

Inicialize the String peso OUTSIDE of this SerialEvent method.

Answer (score 3):

### Foreword

It seems the server is writing on the serial port in 4 chunks, probably 64bits words:

1. 0
2. 0
3. 0
4. .250

You are reading with a max buffer of 64 bits (readBuffer.length * 8 bits), so the last could be:

> 0011111111010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Try it:

```
        String s = "0011111111010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"; 
        double d = Double.longBitsToDouble(Long.parseLong(s,2));
        System.out.println(d); //-> 0.25
```

**As for now nothing is wrong**.

### Answer

Probably you are wanting to process all 4 chunks in a single point, so you could try the following - of course, much depends on the protocol's semantics which I ignore:

```
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event){
            switch(event.getEventType()) {

                case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
                    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[8];
                    String peso = "";
                    try {
                         while (inputStream.available()>0) {
                             int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                             peso += new String (readBuffer, 0, numBytes, "UTF-8");
                         }

                         m_dWeightBuffer = Double.parseDouble(peso);

                    } catch (IOException ex) {}
                    break;

            } 
    }
```

That is, the double is created after all the data is read.

Comment: I'll post in the answer what im getting doing that.